# Null comparison is not happening to the fields in where clause

Tags: oracle

Null comparison is not happening to the fields in where clause.
Code is as below. Its just a sample code where null comparison is not happening.

```
create or replace function document_history
    (V_process_id IN) 
    return varchar2 
AS   
    V_document_id number;         
    V_process_status varchar2(10);   

select document_id, process_status 
into V_document_id, V_process_status 
from document_details 
where process_id =V_process_id ;  

update staging2 
set (country,land) = (select country, land 
                      from staging 
                      where document_id =V_document_id);  
commit;  

return null;  
end document_history;
```

Here if input varible V_document_id is null, sub query will not return any value where I'm expecting the output for null value also.

I tried below scenarios to get output for the subquery:

1. `select country, land from staging where nvl(document_id,'*') = nvl(V_document_id,'*');`
2. `select country, land from staging where document_id = nvl(V_document_id,null);`
3. I declared one variable with `null` value and used in the `nvl` function,
   `nl_variable:=null; 
   select country, land from staging where document_id = nvl(V_document_id,nl_variable);`
4. I tried `trim(V_document_id)`.

Only for 1st option, query would return the value.

Wherein, my real procedure/functions are big and they have many columns in where clause which needs to return the value if input is `null` and I cant use  `nvl(input,'*')` on all the columns in `where` clause and also cant use `IS NULL` (as comparison should be like `(document_id =V_document_id)`).

Could someone help me, how `null` comparison can be done here?

Comment: If  `V_document_id` can be null, then you may not rely on that to use it for  the  update statement . You may require another identifier for selecting the correct rows

Comment: `document_id=null` will never return `true`. so your 2nd and 3rd  methods could't possibly work. The only way is like in your 1st attempt or checking for `is null`

Comment: Also, do you actually use this function that returns `null` like you have shown or is it just a sample code?It would be better to use a `procedure` instead if that's the case.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like I can purpose a solution. This solution, in fact, is a hack

Just replace

```
document_id =V_document_id
```

with

```
decode(document_id,V_document_id,1,0)=1
```

From [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements005.htm)

> However, Oracle considers two nulls to be equal when evaluating a DECODE function. Please refer to DECODE for syntax and additional information.

Comment: Yes, if I use decode function, code will work, but I have many columns in my where clause. Is it fine if I use decode on all of them.